# Python: How to use an item from a python list which appears a specific number of times?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a python list num = [1,2,5,3,4,4] and I know that there is an item which appears 2 times in num. Now I want to use only that item.
Is there a predefined function to choose that item?

*There is no upper limit on value of items in num.

Comment: This might work: http://repl.it/s22

Comment: @JamesMills: nowhere does it ask for what elements appears *consecutively*. They are asking for what element appears 2 times.

Comment: "Appears twice consecutively" or does when the items repeat not matter?

Comment: "appears 2 times" is ambiguous IHMO :) But okay :)

Answer (score 5):

There is no predefined function, no. You'll have to count all the items and figure out which one can be found twice in the list.

You can use a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the counts, and from there it is reasonably easy to enumerate the values that appear twice:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(num)
twice = [n for n, count in counts.iteritems() if count == 2]
```

Comment: I'm not even really sure this question is about keeping a count of items in a list. i.e: using ``Counter()``

Comment: @JamesMills: it is about finding the element(s) that appears twice. But you cannot know what elements appear exactly twice until you have counted them all.

Comment: Well that's what I mean though :) Twice in any order or twice consecutively :) I guess the OP didn't really say!

Comment: @JamesMills: I'd have expected wording like *twice **in a row*** in that case.

Comment: That would be the case (yes) for native English but you can never be sure!

Answer (score 0):

Yes (if the data contains only one repeated item):

```
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter([1,2,5,3,4,4]).most_common(1)[0][1]
2
```

Otherwise you'll have to use `collections.Counter([1,2,5,3,4,4]).most_common()` and search for the element that occurs twice.

A [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) allows you to count elements and determine the most common element. If the data satisfies your assumptions (that there is one element occurring twice) then this approach would allow you to find it.

Comment: So what happens if there are also items that appear 3 or more times?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: hmm, then it wouldn't work. I assumed the data would have only one repeated item but indeed the question does not explicitly state this.